# CodeIgniter language code routing

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I would like to add a language code segment to my URIs in CodeIgniter, but I'd like to somehow — possibly with routing — force the browser to stop interpreting a language code as a path.

I haven't yet successfully implemented any of the i18n libraries in my CodeIgniter install, and I'm fairly certain my problem is simple enough to solve without a library anyway.

The method I had in mind was simply to load the appropriate language files respective of the language code that appears in the URI.

For example

```
http://example.com/about        // Default language
http://example.com/sv/about     // Load Swedish language
```

Here's the controller logic:

```
<?php
//  ** Update **
//  The following updated code works, as long as the language code appears
//  at the end of the URI, e.g, http://example.com/about/sv
//
//  Ideally, I would like the language code segment to always appear first.
//
//  There is also the problem of keeping the language selected while
//  navigating around the site…

class Pages extends CI_Controller {
    public function view ($page = 'home') {

        if (!file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            show_404();

        $uri = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $lang_code = end($uri);

        $data['title'] = $lang_code;

        switch ($lang_code) {
            case "sv": $the_language = "swedish"; break;
            case "no": $the_language = "norwegian"; break;
            default: $the_language = "english";
        }

        $this->lang->load('general',$the_language);
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? If so, why? Please avoid canned responses.

Comment: An alternative solution is to put the selection in a cookie, and then create your own extension to the CI_Controller which attempts to read the language selection (or set default), and place that in `$this->the_language` or similar. Of course having the language code in the URL makes it clear for users what language to expect, so it has it's benefits as well.

Comment: Yeah, for that reason I really want the language code to exist in the URI.

Comment: There's surely a better way to do this (htaccess perhaps) but perhaps you could alter/extend the routing class to check the first URI segment is a language (pseudocode here) `if (in_array(uri_segment(1), array('sv', 'en')) { set_language_var; strip_first_segment_from_uri; } continue routing;`

Comment: My solution is sort of half-way there now (code updated); I don't really understand how uri-routing works.

Comment: There is a built in function `$this->uri->segment(n)` which gives you the segments of the URI without having to do `explode`. As for keeping the language selection you could set `$data['lang_path'] = $lang_code . '/'` if a language is selected (and leave it as an empty string otherwise). Then you will have to prepend all your links with this variable. I again stand with the suggestion of just using a cookie. I think this path will be rather complex once you start passing data to your controller(s).

Comment: @Mudshark I don't understand how that works. This is why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with CI routing:

```
$route['([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)'] = "pages/view/$2";
```

Then, your controller would look something like this:

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access');

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->language = $this->uri->segment(1);
}

function view($page = 'home')
{
    /* other stuff */
    $this->lang->load('general',$this->language);
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
```

}

Comment: That's great! It's beginning to work as I'd like it to. A couple of things though: 1) The language segment now displays the language name, instead of the language code, i.e., `http://example.com/english/home`; How should I shorten it? 2) It needs a language segment, otherwise nothing works, i.e., `http://example.com/home` doesn't work. How can I default the site to English? It shouldn't display the language code in the URI if it's in the default language.

Comment: Bit pressed for time here, but in routes.php you could start off with `$route['default_controller'] = "pages/view/sv";`.  As for english vs en: create an array in the constructor, `$languages = array('en' => english', 'sv' => 'swedish', etc);`, then in your view function determine the language as `$current_lang = $this->languages[$this->language]`

Comment: Your answer has helped considerably, so I'm upvoting and marking as correct. I'm not all the way there yet though, so I'm continuing in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212580/i18n-uris-with-ci-routing-or-mod-rewrite).